# Is there a way I can redirect/rewrite URLs is IIS 7 when the application runs the .NET Framework 1.1?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

Is there simply a way I can update the web.config file to rewrite or redirect URLs without making code changes to the project?

Comment: You can try looking at the Url Rewrite Module on IIS7. http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: @Phill - I did but the elements specified by the module are not supported by the .NET Framework 1.1

Comment: Does it throw an exception when you run the page? In .NET 2.0/4.0 it says the elements are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before IIS7 came out, I used a [URL Rewrite Module](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) from Helicon to do similar things.  It's based on regex for the rules, but it's pretty good and it always worked well for me.

It's an ISAPI module, so it's configuration is outside of web.config.

I used the ISAPI_Rewrite_Lite product, which is free.  I never used the full-blown version.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David however that requires that we purchase the module from Helicon and seeing that we have IIS 7 we would prefer leveraging on what we already have.

Comment: @Peanuts - How many servers would you need to put it on? $99 for a single server isn't too much.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - No problem - totally understand where you're coming from.  I'm going to guess that you're going to be pretty limited in what you can do with IIS7 on a .NET 1.1 Framework.  That's why we looked outside and found Helicon's product.

Comment: @David Hoerster - Thanks. I am suprised that the URL Rewrite module for IIS 7 would not be backwards compatible with the .NET Framework 1.1.

Comment: @Phill - It isn't always about how much it costs because for example the hosting environment may be shared and we may be limited to what we can install, only MS products are supported by the IT team, etc. Appreciate the help though.

Comment: @Peanuts - fair enough. I just assumed the issue was cost since you said 'however that requires that we purchase the module from Helicon'.